# Floating-point conversion without strtod/sprintf

Tags: c, string, floating-point

Since I have decided to use UTF-16 internally in a program that should run on Windows and Linux, I need replacement for some string handling functions, since I do not want to convert to and from the native char representation for user-mode code. However, if float conversion is slow compared to running iconv, I can use a wrapper around strtod/sprintf 
[WINE](http://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-patches/2002-December/004780.html) did.

Comment: Although I can infer what you're trying to ask, having your question explicitly stated would be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These conversions to and from decimal are difficult to make both fast and correct. The naïve (but correct) versions assume multi-precision integers, an implementation of which you were perhaps not planning on depending on.  In short, wrap your existing `stdtod`/`sprintf` and do not worry about the overhead, it will be less than the loss of performance in using a naïve implementation of these functions.

In the “naïve incorrect” category, there is an [implementation of strtod()](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/branches/ruby_1_8/missing/strtod.c) floating around that all interpreters use when the host is lacking one. This implementation is terrible (it may return a result off by several [ULPs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place)), but if you do not mind, you could adapt this code to manipulate UTF-16 characters.

---

NOTE: there is a `swprintf()` in C99 I think, but it is for strings of `wchar_t`, which does not have to be UTF-16, so that may not work for you.

Comment: swprintf works on windows, but for linux i need to iconv first since it uses utf32 or utf8.

Comment: @user877329 I thought this was the reason you did not mention it in your question.